# Using JwPlayer with .net datalist

Tags: jquery, vb.net, jwplayer

I am new to jwplayer and can't figure out how to use it with a datalist.  The datalist will display three images across, and when they click on the image I'd like a video to play as an overlay on the screen, rather than opening a new browser window. The examples I've seen reference a particular element id, but that doesn't work for a datalist, as there are multiple elements with the same name.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a way you can provide an example of where you are trying this?

Comment: I don't have it on a public site right now. This is my code:

Comment: This is my code:

<asp:DataList ID="VideosDataList" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" RepeatColumns="3"
  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="822px">
  <ItemTemplate>
      <div id="video">
          <script type="text/javascript">
              jwplayer("video").setup({
                  file: 'GoadVideos/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VideoName") %>',
                  image: "Images/ClickToPlay.jpg",
                  height: 220,
                  width: 220
              });
          </script>
          <br />
      </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

Comment: Only 1 instance of the div in the datalist is displayed, even tho all three are rendered, with separate video names.  But the problem may be that all the divs have the same id, since that's the way that datalists work in asp.net.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to do it with an onclick? I'm not sure of the syntax of that, since I'm not a java script programmer. I know I'd have to pass the video filename and image name, as well as the dimensions and position. Any ideas?

Comment: You could do onClick and play() - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference, it would be good to see a live link if possible though.